# Creating dynamic jQuery selectors in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

This seems odd and may well be a PEBKAC somewhere... I'm attempting to make a jQuery function which acts on a page element by Id where the Id is populated by the model from an MVC3 site.

I have a form using the Ajax post back helper that looks like this:

```
               <div id="rsvp_@(Model.Meeting.Id)" class="rsvp">
                           <text>You coming or what?</text>
                           using (Ajax.BeginForm("Rsvp", "Member", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "meeting_" + Model.Meeting.Id, OnBegin = "TryRsvp();", OnSuccess = "DidRsvp();", OnFailure = "FailRsvp();"}))
                           {
                               @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentUser.Id);
                               @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Meeting.Id);
                               <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Yes!" />
                               <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="No" />
                           }
                 </div>
```

and when one of the submit buttons is called the javascript for TryRsvp() fires:

```
function TryRsvp() {
    alert('trying to rsvp');
    $('#rsvp_@(Model.Meeting.Id)').toggle();      
    alert('did script');  
}
```

I get both alerts - but the toggle doesn't work.

I've looked at the code being output and the line looks like this:

```
    $('#rsvp_323e52cc-3058-4bfd-9a4f-0cb9653ebe99').toggle();
```

which looks correct.

Oddly - if I hard code the line (i.e. I use firebug to find the generated script and then copy and paste it directly onto the page) then it works fine. However, when MVC3 is generating is dynamically it fails - even though as far as I can see, the resulting javascript is identical.

What's going on here? Is there something about the way MVC3 is delivering the page and the scripts that would make a difference here?

Any clues appreciated

Comment: it could be the fact that the toggle requires jquery and the library is either not loaded when that happens or is inaccessible for some reason. Try changing it to a dom api like `document.getelementById("IDinquestion");` just to check to see if it is indeed being added correctly and it is not a jquery issue.

Comment: I think if jQuery wasn't working then hard coding the Id would fail, but the hard coded script works fine

Comment: It was just a suggestion to weed out the possibilities. Other than that honestly it should be working at least from what I can tell.

Comment: Yah, good point - I'll try out the document.getelementById - just in case something kooky is going on with the jQuery...  curious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, you may have added the `TryRsvp()` to your main page, which  wouldn't work because the element wouldn't have existed in the DOM when the function was parsed.

You need to either specify the class  or output the function along with your form.